# Graphviz dot (or roll my own clone) - how can I auto-arrange panels?

Tags: delphi, graphviz

I would like to read a database schema and show the tables and the keys which link them.

This is the sort of thing that [Graphviz Dot](http://www.graphviz.org/) excels at (e.g, something like [this](http://www.graphviz.org/content/datastruct), but with database tables).

I suppose I could just use Delphi to read the d/b schema, generate a DOT input file, invoke DOT and display the result in a TImage, but I would like to be able to represent the tables as VCL components, clickable with context sensitive menus, etc. More read-write than read-only.

I would also like to do this sort of thing generically, not just with databases.

So, far, so vague & heading for deletion, so it's time for a specific question (or two).

How can I auto-arrange VCL components (let's say TPanel, for instance)?

And how can I link them visually (wth arrows)? So far, I found only TDxfconnector from the [ExpressForum Library](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExForumLibrary/Info.xml), but that seems to limit the connection points to the corners and the middle of the sides. If I had a (badly designed) DB table with 16 indices into another table, how could I link them with arrows?

I think that that breaks down into two cases - static and dynamic (am I just drawing a diagram, or can the user drag the components around & expect the arrows to follow?).

Can this be done, or am I being to ambitious? I am googling for existing VCL components, but with no real luck.

---

[Update] see http://kylecordes.com/2003/graphviz-delphi

Comment: here's something that will reduce your work time http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/simplegraph/

Comment: I wouldn't use panels, but some TGraphicControl descendant and do my own drawing. And that is coming from someone with less experience doing her own drawing than you can imagine...

Comment: @Mawg - all this graph drawing thing is a time sinkhole. It is just fascinating and utterly hopeless (as in _NP-complete_ fascinating.) So unless you plan to spend years toying around with your program just go ahead and use some third-party software for it.

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo  I think that Leonardo had the "correct" answer, but I will award the question to you for that very useful component, if you will just post an answer

Comment: @Mawg thank you, but I'm good, not here for the "karma", I hope you find a solution to your problem, maybe post that as an answer?

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.galapagossoftware.com/developer-tools/pasviz  it's an updated version of the 2003 component you're linking to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only component I'm aware of that is close to what you need is [Simple Graph](http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/simplegraph/) from [delphiarea](http://www.delphiarea.com), while you're there, check out other components, there are many and high quality!